# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python

I am working on my python script to get the list of date format from the 
sqlite database.

I'm creating the variable `startDelta` to get the list of rows from the 
variable called `program_startDate`.

When I use this statement to execute the code, I get a problem with my code:

```
#get the programs list
cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs 
WHERE channel=?', [channel])
programList = list()
programs = cur

for row in programs:
     program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3])
     program_startDate = str(row[2])
     program_endDate = str(row[3])
     programList.append(program)
cur.close()

idx = str(programList)

# find nearest half hour
viewStartDate = datetime.datetime.now()
viewStartDate -= datetime.timedelta(minutes = viewStartDate.minute % 30, 
seconds = viewStartDate.second)

startDelta = program_startDate - viewStartDate
stopDelta = program_endDate - viewStartDate
```

I will get an error:
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

The errors are jumping on this line:

```
startDelta = program_startDate - viewStartDate
stopDelta = program_endDate - viewStartDate
```

How to fix this?

Comment: you force `row[2]` to be a string... so you pushed the error. 
Convert to a datetime object if you want to calculate

Comment: @ngulam yes i actually did. I have stored the strings in the database which is like: 20140831170500. can you tell me how to convert them to a datetime object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is exactly as the error states. `program_startDate` and `program_endDate` are strings, and you're trying to subtract a datetime from them, something python is unable to do.

Are these values stored as datetimes in your database?

If so, use:

```
 program_startDate = row[2]
 program_endDate = row[3]
```

Instead of converting them to strings. The db engine will get them as datetime for you and the error will be solved.

If they're stored as strings in your db, [use datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert them to datetimes according to the format they're stored in.

Edit:

The OP is storing dates as long in the database, such as 20140831170500. To solve the problem, use:

```
from datetime import datetime
...
...
for row in programs:
    program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3])
    program_startDate = datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    program_endDate = datetime.strptime(str(row[3]), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    programList.append(program)
```

Comment: No it isn't. You're converting those to strings, Korem isn't.

Comment: @Korem: Yes I have stored the datetimes in my database. When I try the code you suggest me to use, i have got the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'long' and 'datetime.datetime'`. The error are jumping on the same line. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is this stored as you mentioned above, as long of 20140831170500? If so, you can try `datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

Comment: you mean i should try `program_startDate = datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`? if so i get the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'. any idea?

Comment: @user3848630 I editted my answer to address your issue

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data type you retrieve from the data base table... If you have a "long" (as mentioned in answer to comment above):

convert to a datetime object with:
`program_startdate = datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

Comment: Thank you very much for that, but i get the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'. any idea?

Comment: This means you didn't import right, do like:
 
`from datetime import datetime`

Comment: oh sorry i have forgot to import the `from datetime import datetime` on the top of my code. I can see it have fixed the problem, but when i use this `program_startdate = datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`, I will get an error: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not long`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: so: do a conversion to string to `row[2]`, as you done before:
 
`program_startdate = datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`